# Do not add border first time HTML

Tags: html, css, row, border, html-table

Not sure how to go about this piece of code (CSS):

```
td { 
border-bottom: solid 2px lightgray; 
}
```

(featured in the jsfiddle below), to not function but only for the first button click. The reason behind this is because then there would be 2 bottom borders.

http://jsfiddle.net/julianbuscema/yqh2rqh0/38/

Pretty much on the second button click I want the code to be activated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the style you already have in your question, add :last-child to tr and then style the last td based on that.

```
tr:last-child td {
    border: none!important;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8a0m19z7/